# IPSec site-to-site with/without NAT

Tags: vpn, ipsec, topology

I am connecting my office to a client's network via IPSec. The need is for me to connect directly to internal IPs on their network; there is no need for them to connect to any services on my internal network. I would prefer to not reveal my office network to the other side, suggesting NAT. (All IPs fake.)

```
     -----------
  --/           \--          +--------------+
 /                 \     /---+              |
(   11.11.11.0/16   )----    | 11.11.11.1   |
 \                 /         +------==------+
  --\           /--              === 
     -----------              ===             MY OFFICE
     CLIENT        Internet ==              -----------
                         ===             --/           \--
                      ===               /                 \
             +------==-------+      /--(    10.1.1.0/24    )
             |               |  /---    \                 /
             | 22.22.22.1/30 +--  NAT    --\           /--
             +---------------+              -----------
```

For this, it seems that I could connect from (say) 10.1.1.23 to 11.11.11.45, and yet the "11." network sees all connections from 22.22.22.1. I have a single-address static subnet (22.22.22.1/30), so I believe I can set my encryption domain to 22.22.22.0/30 and use NAT on my end. (The remote end is not using NAT.)

My understanding from https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/45107/43748 is that NAT has a slight penalty to it (not a surprise), but it does not say that it cannot be done. https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/41503 suggests NAT can be used to solve problems with overlapping subnet ranges. Both (and others) tell me that NAT in a site-to-site configuration can be fine.

But the remote side admins "insist" that they must know my office internal subnet to properly function. I think all they need to know for my encryption domain is 22.22.22.0/30, encryption gateway 22.22.22.1, with no internal network defined.

What is my misunderstanding wrt this network topology?

(The specific models, if it matters: my end CheckPoint-790; remote ends are either Cisco ASA or SonicWall, depending on the client.)

Comment: NAT is simply changing (translating) addresses in an IP packet. It doesn't really do anything for security. What provides you security is a firewall, and you can configure the firewall to deny or allow whatever you want to allow or deny.

Comment: Good point, perhaps I should focus my security efforts on rejecting new packets from `11.*/16` to `10.*/24`. Great point, actually. Though I still don't feel they need to know anything about my internal network, including the subnet: security-by-obscurity should never be relied on, but it still has a net-positive effect as a layer on top of other (strong) security techniques.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one site has the internal address space of 11.11.0.0/16 and the other has 10.1.1.0/24, then technically you do not have [Overlapping networks on either side of the VPN tunnel](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/vpn-overlapping-networks/).

If you want the 11.11.0.0/16 network to speak directly to the 10.1.1.0/24 network, then you don't need any type of NAT.

If you want the 11.11.0.0/16 network to speak to another network, but have that other network be translated to 10.1.1.0/24, then you would need to set up a [Policy NAT](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/nat/policy-nat-twice-nat/#policy-nat).

For example, if you wanted to hide the 10.1.1.0/24 network as the 22.1.1.0/24 network, you would set up a Policy NAT on the Router/Firewall *on the 10.1.1.0/24* network that essentially says:

> *When 10.1.1.0/24 is speaking to 11.11.0.0/16, translate the 10.1.1.0/24 network to 22.1.1.0/24.*

You could use either a [Static NAT](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/nat/static-nat/) if you want each IP in the 10.1.1.0/24 to map to something unique in the 22.1.1.0/24 network. Or you could use a [Dynamic PAT](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/nat/dynamic-pat/) if you want the entire 10.1.1.0/24 network to appear as a single address (aka 22.1.1.200).

Either way, the OTHER side will only need to know about the 22.1.1.x network -- they will NOT have to know about your internal 10.1.1.0/24 network.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that I *can* use NAT on this site-to-site, and the other side only needs to know about the 22.*/30 network. I feel like I'm going crazy sometimes dealing with different admins projecting preference and assumptions over topological requirements.

Comment: @r2evans, remember that NAT breaks some protocols and applications, and there may be a legitimate requirement to not use NAT.

Comment: I know some things break with NAT, but none of my current network needs would: ssh, sql, et al. Thanks, it's important to keep that in mind.